# Pre-determining the count of permutations

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, permutations

I have an algorithm in code working for a string permutation. For example, for the character set of `'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'`, it generates 12 permutations of the string which is equivalent to `4! / 2!`. When I allow repetitions within that algorithm, it produces `256` for the following character set: `'A', 'D', 'B', 'C'` which is equivalent to `4^4`.

Finally, I can also control the length. For example for `'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'` character set, it can generate `6! / (6-2)!` permutations.

However, I am having problems pre-determining how many permutations will be generated when the string length of characters is less than the count of characters within the character set and the character set contains duplicates. For example:

- The character set: `'A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'`
- Length: `3`

I can run the algorithm and see that the result is `72` with the below permutations:

`AAC, AAD, AAE, AAF, ACA, ACD, ACE, ACF, ADA, ADC, ADE, ADF, AEA, AEC, AED, AEF, AFA, AFC, AFD, AFE, CAA, CAD, CAE, CAF, CDA, CDE, CDF, CEA, CED, CEF, CFA, CFD, CFE, DAA, DAC, DAE, DAF, DCA, DCE, DCF, DEA, DEC, DEF, DFA, DFC, DFE, EAA, EAC, EAD, EAF, ECA, ECD, ECF, EDA, EDC, EDF, EFA, EFC, EFD, FAA, FAC, FAD, FAE, FCA, FCD, FCE, FDA, FDC, FDE, FEA, FEC, FED`

Does anyone know what the formula is here to reach to `72`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case not all elements are regarded, the order matters and no repetition is allowed (The double A case can be considered later). Here you have **variation without repetition**. The formula is

$V_{n,k}=\binom{n}{k}\cdot k!$

You have $n=5$ and $k=3$. Here the elements are $A,C,D,E,F$. Thus

$V_{n,k}=\binom{5}{3}\cdot 3!=10\cdot 6=60$

Now you consider the double A´s: $AAX$

$X$ can take the letters $C,D,E,F$ ($4$ elements). The three elements can be ordered in three ways, because  $X$ can be on the first, second or third place.  Therefore the number of arranging $AAX$ is $3\cdot 4=12$. The sum of both results gives $72$.

Comment: thanks! One question: for $V_{n,k}=\binom{5}{3}\cdot 3!=10\cdot 6=60$, how did you get the `10` there?

Comment: Found it: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Evaluate_binomial_coefficients

Comment: @tugberk That´s nice. Two simplification can be made, because some factors can be cancelled. They make the calculation more simple: **Firstly** $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k} $. For $n=5$ and $k=3$ we get $\binom{5}{5-3}=\binom{5}2$. And **secondly**  $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n\times (n-1)\times \ldots\times (n-k+1)}{1\times 2\times \ldots \times k}$. For $n=5$ and $k=2$ we finally  get $\binom{5}{2}=\frac{5\cdot 4 }{1\cdot 2}=10$.

Answer (score 0):

Let your  multiset have multiplicities  $q_k$ where $1\le k\le  m$ and
$m$   is  the   number  of   types  of   different  letters   and  let
$p=\sum_{k=1}^m q_k.$ We assign slots to each type of letter where the
letter may receive between zero and  $q_k$ slots. To get the answer we
extract the  value for $n$ slots  supposing that $n$ is  the length of
the selection that we were given. This gives the combinatorial species

$$\mathfrak{P}_{0\le\cdot\le q_1}(\mathcal{Z})
\mathfrak{P}_{0\le\cdot\le q_2}(\mathcal{Z})
\times \cdots \times
\mathfrak{P}_{0\le\cdot\le q_m}(\mathcal{Z}).$$

which produces the formula

$$n! [z^n] \prod_{k=1}^m \left(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{6}
+ \cdots + \frac{z^{q_k}}{q_k!}\right).$$

Compare  to the  naive method  of  sieving all  combinations which  is
exponential. The order of terms here is $p$ as opposed to $m^n.$

The  Maple code  follows which  implements enumeration  as  well as
count by formula.

```
with(combinat);

X :=
proc(L, n)
option remember;

    nops([seq(seq(el, el in permute(ch)),
              ch in choose(L, n))]);
end;

F :=
proc(L, n)
option remember;
local gf, mset;

    mset := convert(L, `multiset`);
    gf := mul(add(z^p/p!, p=0..op(2, mset[q])),
              q=1..nops(mset));

    n!*coeff(expand(gf), z, n);
end;
```

Here we see Maple allocate memory  as we try to solve a more difficult
problem instance and then calculate  the answer instantly by using the
formula.

```
> X([seq(seq(A[q], p=1..q), q=1..5)], 10);
memory used=875.4MB, alloc=40.3MB, time=149.99
memory used=880.4MB, alloc=40.8MB, time=150.11
memory used=904.8MB, alloc=56.1MB, time=150.65
memory used=918.1MB, alloc=344.1MB, time=151.50
memory used=952.2MB, alloc=344.1MB, time=152.78
memory used=999.7MB, alloc=376.1MB, time=154.76
memory used=1070.6MB, alloc=408.1MB, time=157.63
memory used=1119.7MB, alloc=408.1MB, time=160.38
memory used=1202.1MB, alloc=440.1MB, time=164.15
memory used=1300.9MB, alloc=472.1MB, time=168.99
memory used=1407.6MB, alloc=504.1MB, time=174.97
                                     1373820

> F([seq(seq(A[q], p=1..q), q=1..5)], 10);
                                     1373820
```

For the question posed by the OP we get

```
> F([A,A,C,D,E,F], 3);                    
                                                72

> X([A,A,C,D,E,F], 3);
                                                72
```